# Rebasing from stash, strange result

Tags: git

I'm just asking this out of curiosity. There are other ways to deal with this kind of situation in real life, but I find the following behavior of git a bit strange.

**Summary:** Stashing creates, behind the curtain, two commits, one contains the index and the other the non-added edits. If we checkout the latter and try to rebase it, we somehow only get the changes from the index. Why is that?

Detailed example follows:

First let's make a repo with one commit, then one more edit that is added to index, then one more edit that is not added to index, and then stash:

```
git init
echo 1 > a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -m"First commit"
echo 2 >> a.txt
git add a.txt
echo 3 >> a.txt
git stash
git log --all --graph --oneline

  *   5c00fc0 WIP on master: c8af537 First commit
  |\  
  | * 965c986 index on master: c8af537 First commit
  |/  
  * c8af537 First commit
```

So `git stash` seems to save both the index and the non-added edit as commits with their own hashes (in my case, 965c986 for index and 5c00fc0 for the non-added edits).

Now edit a new file and commit:

```
echo x >> b.txt
git add b.txt
git commit -m"Second commit"
```

So all of the commits now look like:

```
git log --all --graph --oneline

  * b589f50 Second commit
  | *   5c00fc0 WIP on master: c8af537 First commit
  | |\  
  |/ /  
  | * 965c986 index on master: c8af537 First commit
  |/  
  * c8af537 First commit
```

Say, we now want to take the stashed edits and combine them with the second commit. There are other ways to do this (like `git stash apply`, but what if we already had cleaned the stash, and then digged the commit from the reflog), but let's just try with:

```
git checkout 5c00fc0
[warning message here]
cat a.txt
  1
  2
  3
git rebase master
  First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
  Applying: index on master: c8af537 First commit
```

But now, the resulting file `a.txt` is just:

```
cat a.txt 
  1
  2
```

This is the whole graph:

```
git log --all --graph --oneline
  * 5fc3ade index on master: c8af537 First commit
  * b589f50 Second commit
  | *   5c00fc0 WIP on master: c8af537 First commit
  | |\  
  |/ /  
  | * 965c986 index on master: c8af537 First commit
  |/  
  * c8af537 First commit
```

So it looks like, even though we checked out commit 5c00fc0, the rebase only applied the changes from the commit 965c986, i.e. the edits that were in the index when we stashed. But whatever was in 5c00fc0 has been ignored.

**Question:** Why is that? Is there some some reasonable explanation for this behavior? Or should this be considered a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, git just (by default) ignores merge commits when rebasing. And stashing creates the WIP commit and the index commit, and the WIP commit is a merge, since it has both the index commit and the c8af537 as parents.

Nothing to do with stashing as such.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it would ignore the index commit though. Rebasing usually removes merge commits but that doesn't mean it drops the code that was merged.

Comment: It doesn't ignore the index commit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue this morning after dropping a stash by accident in a GUI app. At first I tried rebasing as others have done, because it's the natural thing to do. Then I used duckduckgo to search and found this, but no actual solution. So I tried a bit harder and came up with this:

Assuming we have the following branches/refs:

- **droppedStash** pointing at the artificial merge commit with the desired
  content
- **parentOfStash** pointing at the original base commit for this
  ex-stash branch

Then we can simply do:

1. git checkout parentOfStash
2. git cherry-pick -m 1 droppedStash

Where -m 1 tells git to consider one of the ancestors to be mainline. Ta da! Enjoy :-)

Answer (score -1):

Massive edit to my original answer.

I did some diving into the code and some testing of my own and I found the issue. When you do your rebase on your headless branch you rebase master. The rebase command verifies the head of the branch you are rebasing, which does not include the stash in this case. Try this instead:

```
git checkout -b stashbranch 5c00fc0
git rebase stashbranch
git log --oneline --decorate --all
```

You should see something like:

```
b589f50 (HEAD, refs/stash, stashbranch) Second commit
```

Note: If you are in a detached head state but run `git rebase master` it will, according to my tests, set your head to the master head. You could have done git rebase 5c00fc0 and achieved the same results I did with branching.

Comment: Looks like you didn't understand that (above) the commits 5c00fc0 and 965c986 are created by the stash command.

Comment: I do understand that. You're still trying to get around the normal behaviour of the stash command.

Comment: Yes, the case above is maybe abuse, or at least not very normal use. But IMHO it's not intuitive that if I try to rebase `5c00fc0`, then `5c00fc0` is **not** rebased, but `965c986` is. In what sense is this protective? Had I wanted to rebase `965c986`, I could rebase from `965c986` could I not.

Comment: The whole point of stashing is that it hides your code away from things like rebasing. Rebasing will not replay WIP commits because it identifies them as WIP commits which are not meant to be merged in.

Comment: After some testing and research I revised my answer.